# jQuery - DOM element is removed but child element count is still the same

Tags: jquery

I have a basic jquery script that detect element removal and count its child elements. But the child element count is not changed although the element is removed.

Here is my HTML script

```
<div>
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <p>Test 2</p>
  <p id="p3">Test 3</p>
</div>
<input type=submit value='Remove Test 3' id=submit-btn />
```

And my jQuery script

```
   $('#submit-btn').click(function()
   {
        $('#p3').remove();
   });

   $("div").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function () {
        //confirm the element removal
        console.log("removed");

        //get child element count
        console.log(this.childElementCount);
    });
```

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/luan123z/zjaxgvad/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would listen for the `DOMSubtreeModified` event instead. With `DOMNodeRemoved` it seems you need to have some type of delay for it to report the right count. Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjaxgvad/5/

Comment: To add to this, it's because `DOMNodeRemoved` is "dispatched before the node is removed from the tree". Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/DOM3-Events.html